# How to separate last expression in repeated expressions in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros

I'd like to have [this macro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e14438161cfcc635546dbd050e4298c6):

```rust
macro_rules! macro1 {
    ($f1:expr, $($f2:expr),+, $f3:expr) => {
        $f1(|a| {
            $(
                $f2(a, |b| {
                    $f3(a, b);
                });
            )*
        });
    }
}
```

This, however, errors with `local ambiguity when calling macro` macro1`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs expr ('f3') or expr ('f2').`. I can resolve this error if I replace the last `,` in the macro rule with a `;` instead so it clearly separates the repeated `f2` and the last `f3`, but I'd like to keep the comma if possible to resemble a function. I can also swap `f2` and `f3`, but in my code `f2` tends to be very short and `f3` will be quite long, so I'd like to also keep this order if possible.

Is there another way to write this macro to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only with the very powerful but hard to understand [TT munching](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html):

```rust
macro_rules! macro1 {
    ($f1:expr, $($f2_and_3:expr),+) => {
        macro1! { @transpose $f1, [ ] $($f2_and_3),+ }
    };
    (@transpose $f1:expr, [ $($f2_parsed:expr,)* ] $f2:expr, $($f2_rest_and_3:expr),+ ) => {
        macro1! { @transpose $f1, [ $($f2_parsed,)* $f2, ] $($f2_rest_and_3),+ }
    };
    (@transpose $f1:expr, [ $($f2:expr,)+ ] $f3:expr ) => {
        $f1(|a| {
            $(
                $f2(a, |b| {
                    $f3(a, b);
                });
            )*
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first @transpose internal rule, why isn't a `,` needed between the `]` and the `$f2:expr`? Doesn't the repetition just before say that a comma is required?

Comment: @Ana Because I didn't put it in the arms producing it. You can do either, it doesn't matter.