match the very last argument of a Rust macro as a closure
Is there a way to adjust the macro below, in order to detect when the last argument of the macro call is a closure? The code below works, but it's using a semicolon to disambiguate, and that doesn't look right.
Could the closure argument be identified specifically at invocation, e.g. closure: || { ... }?
macro_rules! invoke_me {
    ($func_name:ident, $($arg:expr),*; || $closure:expr ) => {{
        println!("{}({})", stringify!($func_name), stringify!($($arg),*));
        println!("With closure");
        let result: Result<(),String> = $closure;
        result
    }};
    ($func_name:ident, $($arg:expr),*) => {{
        println!("{}({})", stringify!($func_name), stringify!($($arg),*));
        println!("No closure");
        Ok::<(),String>(())
    }};
}

fn main() {
    invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3).unwrap();
    invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3; || {
        println!("Ok from closure");
        Ok(())
    }).unwrap();
    let _ = invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3; || {
        println!("Error from closure");
        Err("Error".to_string())
    });
}


this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203742/how-to-separate-last-expression-in-repeated-expressions-in-a-rust-macro
probably have to tt/expr munch to split of the last expr and then pattern match on the closure.

Using the idea from How to separate last expression in repeated expressions in a Rust macro? (see ChrisB's comment), I got this to work:
macro_rules! invoke_me {
    ($func_name:expr, $($rest:tt)+) => {
        invoke_me!(@transpose $func_name, [ ] $($rest)+)
    };
    (@transpose $func_name:expr, [ $($args:expr)*] || $closure:expr) => {{
        println!("{}({})", stringify!($func_name), stringify!($($args),*));
        println!("With closure");
        let result: Result<(),String> = $closure;
        result
    }};
    (@transpose $func_name:expr, [$($temp:expr)*] $arg:expr , $($rest:tt)+) => {
        invoke_me!(@transpose $func_name, [$($temp)* $arg] $($rest)+)
    };
    (@transpose $func_name:expr, [$($args:expr)*] $last_arg:expr) => {{
        println!("{}({})", stringify!($func_name), stringify!($($args),*, $last_arg));
        println!("No closure");
        Ok::<(),String>(())
    }}
}

fn main() {
    invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3).unwrap();
    invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3, || {
        println!("Ok from closure");
        Ok(())
    }).unwrap();
    let _ = invoke_me!(foo, 1, 2, 3, || {
        println!("Error from closure");
        Err("Error".to_string())
    });
}

playground
Although this is possible, it would probably be a better idea to just keep the semicolon, as this is slow.

Thanks a lot for sharing this technique. It works indeed! I assume you mean slow compilation time, as the macro is recursive.
